# Blender can't find python module 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, blender

I apologize in advance for the lack of experience. This is my first time using Blender.

I am trying to import openpyxl in a python file in Blender, however, I keep getting the error message: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'". I have openpyxl installed and my PATH should be set up.

[image: Location of openpyxl]

I've also tried adding 'openpyxl' to a scripts folder and adding that location to my user preferences, which also didn't work.

[image: Blender preferences]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Install pip** (Python's package management system). To do this, download the file [file get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to the folder with the python.exe file of Blender itself (for example): `cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python\bin`
   and install pip: `python.exe get-pip.py`
2. **Installing packages**: After installing pip, we have a Scripts folder containing pip.exe: `cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python\Scripts` Install the packages of interest to it: `pip.exe install openpyxl`

Download pip using cmd:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --ssl-no-revoke -o get-pip.py`